# Unity - Selecting screen/display in Agora screen sharing app for Windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am trying to develop a screen sharing app for Windows in Unity with the help of Agora. When I use the function StartScreenCaptureByScreenRect() I successfully capture either the whole VirtualScreen or
the primary screen. I have trouble when I try to capture an other/secondary display.

My setup is 2 monitors 1920x1080. When I try to use Screen.AllScreens (it should return an array containing all displays on the system) from System.Windows.Forms, for example, it doesn't return two 1920x1080 monitors, it returns one 3840x1080 monitor in position (0,0) [the layout is {primary}{secondary} ].

What I actually want to do is find the "coordinates" of each screen/display inside the VirtualScreen (except the primary which I know is (0,0)).
I though the Screen class was what I needed but it doesn't seem to have the functionality I need.
Am I doing something wrong or should I change my approach?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get the position and resolution of each screen (x,y,width,height) but I have an other problem now. If the screen is above and/or left of the primary screen, y and/or x will be negative. Then I instantiate a Rectangle to pass it to StartScreenCaptureByScreenRect() and the function returns an invalid arguments error. It works only for positive x and y (if the screen is below and/or right of the primary screen).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I am trying to do the same. I've only managed to share unity editor window. Is it possible to share your source code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but I can give you some hints. First of all you should use v3 Agora SDK. If you try to get display info from Unity functions you will get details about your game screen, you should use the C# class Screen from System.Windows.Forms.dll to get details about your displays. This class also didn't work so I had to implement it myself, if you search you will most likely find in github an implementation. After all this you will have something like this Screen.AllScreens which is a list of all displays, you will need x,y,width,height for each display.

Comment: I've get the allscreens data. But couldn't see a windowId in it. Whatever I tried i've couldn't share the screen when i minimaze the unity window.

Comment: Create a Rectangle with the values x,y,width,height you got and pass it in StartScreenCaptureByScreenRect(), see Rick Chengs answer for reference. You don't need windowid.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is different here.  You are not doing anything wrong.  If you can obtain that 3840x1080 resolution then you are very close to share the second display. The rectangle (1920,0, 1920, 1080) is the region rect you want to put.  E.g. consider the following code:

```
TestRectCrop(0);  // display 1
TestRectCrop(1);  // display 2

void TestRectCrop(int order)
{
    // Assuming you have two display monitors, each of 1920x1080, position left to right:
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle() { x = 0, y = 0, width = 1920 * 2, height = 1080 };
    Rectangle regionRect = new Rectangle() { x = order * 1920, y = 0, width = 1920, height = 1080 };

    int rc = mRtcEngine.StartScreenCaptureByScreenRect(screenRect,
        regionRect,
        default(ScreenCaptureParameters)
        );
    if (rc != 0) Debug.LogWarning("rc = " + rc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am not looking for a hardcoded solution that works only for this case/layout, imagine if I had 4 displays with whatever resolutions in what ever layout just adding an offset to x and/or y will not work for every possible layout. Thanks again.

Comment: I am only getting a white box when trying to share screen with StartScreenCaptureByScreenRect. Any idea?

Comment: Try mRtcEngine.StartScreenCaptureByScreenRect(default(Rectangle),default(Rectangle),default(ScreenCaptureParameters)). If you dont get white screen you where passing invalid arguments. If you get white screen again you probably doing something wrong with videosurface.

Comment: Also make sure you updated to the latest SDK ver. 3.0.1.72, which was released last Friday at the Asset Store.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update if case you found this thread and looking for screensharing example - we have [an improved example here](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Unity-Quickstart/blob/master/API-Example-Unity/Assets/API-Example/desktop-screen-share-sample/DesktopScreenShare.cs), please use this to test and adapt your desktop screensharing implementation.